# Neo4j graphql before insert... Triggers

Tags: neo4j, graphql

How do I add on before update, create and delete listeners to graphql?

Particularly on a level of operation, node, properties of the operation. Not as nested actions.
For example, if I wanted to run custom validation for each node, send emails under certain objects.

Of course resolvers can accomplish something like this, but it sounds too manual for getting just the all requests to update a node will pass through this function before updating